# Handle custom response messages with Parse-server 3.0.0+

Tags: parse-server

I have a project where it uses Parse-server 2.8.1 version. This was previously communicated with mLab and with the current migration to MongoDBAtlas, we have to update the parse-server version to the latest. I have seen there was a migrating doc. But there is a part which I not getting yet. How to set custom response messages. For example

```
        if (users.length > 0){
            response.success({
                status:false,
                message:'Screen name has already been taken.'
            });
        } else {
            response.success({
                status:true,
                message:'Screen name available.'
            });
        }
```

How to convert this to support the parse-server latest version. This is a must since mobile apps are communicating with the server, depending on these status values and the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```js
Parse.Cloud.define('myFunctionName', async () => {
  const query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  // add some constraints to query
  const users = await query.find({ useMasterKey: true });
  if (users.length > 0) {
    return {
      status: false,
      message: 'Screen name has already been taken.'
    };
  } else {
    return {
      status:true,
      message:'Screen name available.'
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: Got it worked... Thank you. I was just missed the await query line.